# How to pull down the list of all files in the asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to browse the whole directory of ASP.NET project. And list all the files in different categories like ASPX, ASCX etc.

Can anyone suggest which asp.net command will be helpful?

Thanks

Comment: Although I've provided an answer, it would be nice to understand why do you need such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var aspxFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.aspx");
```

But it is worrying that you need such functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it for my assignment. I am a student.